# Javascript: which function is used if there are several possibilities?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellij-idea, datatables

If I look for the definition of a javascript function like `destroy()` in IDEA intellij by pressing the F2 key:

```
var myTable = $('#myList').dataTable({
    columns: listHeader,
    data: listBody
});

myTable.destroy();
```

I can see several definitions:

```
destroy in Chart.PluginBase (chart.bundle.js, static) 
destroy in Chart.DatasetController (chart.bundle.js, static) 
destroy in DataTable.defaults (jquery.dataTables.js, static) 
destroy in u (angular-material.min.js, static) 
destroy in v (angular-material.min.js, static) 
destroy in r (angular-material.min.js, static)
```

How can I enforce that the wanted function is used?

Comment: It will call `destroy` of `dataTable`, as `myTable` is a reference of it.

Comment: @Sushanth-- and how could I test programmatically that myTable really is a reference of DataTable? (in Java, there would be something like: `instanceOf`)

Comment: You could use `instanceof` operator to check if the object created is from the expected constructor. `console.log(myTable instanceof dataTable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ask yourself what type your object is of and you'll have the answer. On line 1 you're assigning $('#myList').dataTable() to your var, so now your var is inheriting the properties (including the function properties) of of the dataTable object. So when you now do myTable.destroy(), this will be using dataTable#destroy (the 3rd one in your list there).

This is one example of a feature of [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Inheriting_methods).

EDIT: Further to your question about "how can I make sure what type my object is of"... the short of it is really "you can't", not reliably anyhow. Javascript is simply not a statically typed language.. and it allows for some pretty **AWESOME** things. But, if you're interested, look into [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)